# TypeError: b is undefined, if number of row in the result set is less than the pageLength

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable plugin for pagination with server side processing. The page is loading fine with data. But if entering some text in search-box, it is giving 'TypeError: b is undefined'. This happens only if the number of rows is less than the page length. For example, if page length is 10 and number of rows in the result set is 11, then it would not throw any error, but if it is 9 then it will throw error. I am using the latest version of jquery and datatable plugins

Below is my code

```
$('#example').dataTable({            
        "iDisplayLength": 100,
        "pageLength": 100,
        "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 500],
       "bProcessing": true,   
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
                "url": "/admincp/exportdata/branch",
                "type": "POST",
                "cache" : false,
                "headers": { "cache-control": "no-cache" }
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "code" },
                { "data": "name" },                    
                { "data": "action" }                            
        ]
})
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post response from the server in JSON format when number of results is more than page size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved as follows

1. Add additional empty rows to original rows so that number of rows equal to page length. This makes the number of rows to display and page length are always equal.
2. This will display empty rows. To avoid that, add a class to empty rows using 'DT_RowClass' property and make it hidden in css file